# A wave is passing through a potential barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let assume a wave is passing through a potential barrier. Like this:

[image]

What will be happened to the amplitude or the shape of the wave during the movement through the  potential barrier? {assuming the energy of the wave  is less than the potential barrier}

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/general-question-about-the-potential-barrier-problem-why-does-exp-kx-diver?rq=1   this might be related

Comment: This is a fairly 'standard' example of quantum tunnelling, see full derivation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier. Also here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html